# DataError at /admin/message/messages/add/ django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

hello i am following a tutorial on how to add a chat function in django rest framework
which is here:

https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@ajmaln/part-1-creating-a-simple-chat-app-with-djangorestframework

but when i create a message in the admin panel it comes up with

```
DataError at /admin/message/messages/add/
invalid input syntax for type integer: "test1"
LINE 1: ...me_id", "time", "seen", "timestamp") VALUES ('o', 'test1', '...
```

i have follwed the whole tutorial but instead of using id as the pk i have used my username column which is a primary key

if you need more data please let me know

is there anything i am missing?

```
class Users(AbstractBaseUser):
    options = (
        ('united kingdom', 'United Kingdom'),
        ('uk', 'UK'),
    )

    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=False)
    birthday = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
    seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    terms_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=15, max_digits=17, null=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=15, max_digits=17, null=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=7, null=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=options)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'birthday', 'id']

    @property
    def distance(self, lat_a, long_a, lat_b, long_b):
        EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES = 3958.761
        """all angles in degrees, result in miles"""
        lat_ab = radians(lat_a)
        lat_b = radians(lat_b)
        delta_long = radians(long_a - long_b)
        cos_x = (
                sin(lat_ab) * sin(lat_b) +
                cos(lat_ab) * cos(lat_b) * cos(delta_long)
        )
        return acos(cos_x) * EARTH_RADIUS_IN_MILES


    objects = MyUserManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_staff
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of speculation, but I see `"...me_id"` in that debug SQL output which *probably* unfolds to `username_id`. That would explain the error, because your app indeed maps a string to field that expects integers.

*Probably* you did not run migrations aka `./manage.py makemigrations && ./manage.py migrate`

That means the python code sees the ForeignKey from Message to User and knows that it maps to its primary key which from Python's perspective is `username`, so it provides the username as the primary key field of the User class which I assume is `"test1"`. However, migrations has not run, so from the database's perspective the primary key is `id`. That's why the mismatch *could* happen.

If running migrations does not fix your issue, please provide your models for User and Message and the full debug statement without truncation.

Comment: yeah i migrated it before and it was giving the issue let me add the user model